# Вывод суммы значений обьектов

Tags: javascript, html, css

Функция `f13` должна вывести сумму значений массива `a13` но для начала нужно проверить сам массив на наличие чисел и потом выводить их суму.Помогите найти решение и исправить ошибки.

```
let a13 = {
    'prim': 'hello',
    'one': 4,
    'testt': 'vodoley',
    'ivan': 6
};

function f13() {
    let c = ''
    let b = document.querySelector('.out-13');
    for (let key in a13) {
        if (a13[key] === number) {
            c += a[key] + a[key];
        }
    }
    b.innerHTML = c;
}

document.querySelector('.b-13').onclick = f13;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typeof` забыли подставить для проверки на number.
"number" в кавычках должен быть.
И вот эта запись в таком виде должна быть `c += a13[key]`

```
let a13 = {
    'prim': 'hello',
    'one': 4,
    'testt': 'vodoley',
    'ivan': 6
};

function f13() {
    let c = 0
    let b = document.querySelector('.out-13');
    for (let key in a13) {
        if (typeof(a13[key]) === 'number') {
            c += a13[key]
        }
    }
    b.innerHTML = c;
}

document.querySelector('.b-13').onclick = f13;
```

Comment: почти верно нужно суму но вместо суммы происходит конкатенация чисел 46

Comment: @Joker 15 да, спасибо, у себя в примере c = 0 задавал, а здесь забыл поправить